# Mount server folder locally on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, sftp

I generally use Linux systems for most of my work, and some work I need to do on specific machines as I can only run certain software on each machine. I have a Windows 7 machine on which I have Publisher 2013, and need to access and modify files on a Linux machine.

If it was a Linux machine, I could use the 'Connect to server' function integrated into the File Manager (Nautilus, Nemo, etc) to connect over FTP or SFTP (FTP over SSH, sort of):
[image: sftp://user@192.168.1.25]

This mounts the attached 'server' as a folder on the machine, meaning files can be modified remotely as though they were attached locally.
[image: so i can open files in programs locally, but they are saved remotely so no local copy needed]

I am aware of FTP clients like Filezilla, but I think this would involve manually transferring files to update them in the local and remote directories. <sub>I also know about SMB/samba, I would prefer to use SFTP (please).</sub>

Is there a alternative I can use on Windows 7 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a number of 3rd-party tools that will enable something like this on Windows.

- [Swish](http://www.swish-sftp.org/)
- [Netdrive](http://www.netdrive.net/)
- [win-sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/)

are three that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier option is to use [sshfs-win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win).
and here is how to go about it based on the official [docs](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win):

> Installation
>
> ---
>
> - Install the latest version of [WinFsp](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/releases/latest).
> - Install the latest version of [SSHFS-Win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win/releases). Choose the x64 or x86 installer according to your computer's architecture.
>
> Basic Usage
>
> ---
>
> Once you have installed WinFsp and SSHFS-Win you can map a network
> drive to a directory on an SSHFS host using Windows Explorer or the
> net use command.
>
> Windows Explorer
> ----    In Windows Explorer select This `PC > Map Network Drive` and enter the desired drive letter and SSHFS path using the following UNC
> syntax: `\\sshfs\REMUSER@HOST[\PATH]`
>
> The first time you map a particular SSHFS path you will be prompted
> for the SSHFS username and password. You may choose to save these
> credentials with the Windows Credential Manager in which case you will
> not be prompted again.
>
> In order to unmap the drive, right-click on the drive icon in Windows
> Explorer and select Disconnect.
>
> [image]

Side note:
In case you want to access a specifc directory and not home directory, when you are setting  the map network, you can do :

```
\\sshfs\username@address\your_relative_path
```

example :

```
\\sshfs\rika@192.168.254.29\..\mnt\something
```